# Building Spoon CtElements for a CtCodeSnippetStatement without strict compiling

Tags: java, inria-spoon

Is there a way to build CtElement’s for a CtCodeSnippetStatement without fully compiling? I have snippets I’d like to be able to scan and further process, before inserting them into a class with the rest of their dependencies (methods / global variables which the snippet may reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you by "without fully compiling" mean that you don't want Spoon to resolve type references in the compiled snippet then you can try:

```
Environment env = new StandardEnvironment();
env.setInputClassLoader(new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{}, null));
Factory factory = new FactoryImpl(new DefaultCoreFactory(),env);
CtCodeSnippetStatement statement = factory.createCodeSnippetStatement("pkg.MyClass myClass = new pkg.MyClass();");
CtStatement compiledStatement = statement.compile();
```

An environment is used here without input resources and it will prevent the system classloader from accessing the classpath. Elements in `compiledStatement` will return `null` with `getDeclaration`, and return `null` with `getTypeDeclaration` for accesses to user-defined classes.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you!